# The best way to run periodically function on C#

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatchertimer

In my WPF application one of the assumptions is watching a folder to capture changes.

My first idea is:

```
DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
dt.Tick += (senderTick, eTick) =>
{
     // do observable folder
};
dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
dt.Start();
```

The example works but I do not know if it is the best solution. My other idea is use Reactive Extenison

```
var timer = Observable.Interval(Timespan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
timer.Subscribe(tick => OnSomeCondition());
```

However, I am not convinced.
Maybe there are better spoosby?
Maybe it would be a good idea to write a separate application as a Windows service that would do it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Running a Windows service would be one idea and I would say it depends on the situation you have. Have you considered IO [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: RX looks cool and I would like to learn it, it's the first application I have for him in my application. Which I can implement without modifying the old code.

Comment: Bypass operation on files which is better for performing cyclic code operations?